# R doesn't accept inserting vector when its length is big

Tags: r, rstudio

R doesn't accept the following code when its size is around 500.
`x<-c(my_data)`

I want to assign array of numeric values(or simply vector) into object `x`.

`x<-c(1,2,3)` %OK

%This doesn't work

```
x<-c(11210., 11252., 11546.5, 12746.5, 11560., 10792.5, 10830., 11394.5, 11117., 11110., 11398., 11631.5, 11127., 9990., 10132., 9008., 8807.5, 9226.5, 8151., 6889.5, 7674.5, 7598.5, 8232.5, 8675.5, 8548.5, 8065., 8905.5, 8499.5, 9462.5, 10008., 10185.5, 11144., 10402., 11173., 11220., 10455., 9831.5, 10130.5, 9689., 9590.5, 10317., 10530., 10319., 10919.5, 11030., 11457.5, 11490.5, 11331.5, 10730., 9913.5, 9304.5, 9224., 8789.5, 9543., 9093., 9133.5, 8190.5, 8250.5, 8250.5, 7849., 8189., 8590., 8897., 8893.5, 8700., 8921., 8512., 8444.5, 8150., 7791., 7935., 7082., 6820., 6920.5, 6817., 7046.5, 7408.5, 6779., 6769.5, 6612., 6900.5, 7014., 6763., 6824., 6933.5, 7904.5, 7887.5, 8000., 8346.5, 8047., 7889.5, 8177., 8266., 8847., 8923.5, 8800., 8943., 9675.5, 8844., 9288., 8928., 9343.5, 9401., 9250.5, 9065.5, 9216., 9742., 9682.5, 9829., 9601., 9359., 9190.5, 9305.5, 9027., 8413., 8476., 8693., 8678., 8477.5, 8332., 8058.5, 8233., 8230., 8521.5, 8397., 7989., 7506., 7568., 7464.5, 7323., 7336.5, 7111., 7469., 7372., 7485.5, 7513., 7631., 7709., 7615.5, 7657., 7689.5, 7625.5, 7492.5, 6767., 6870.5, 6553.5, 6296., 6631.5, 6394.5, 6488., 6443., 6707., 6732., 6750., 6710.5, 6049., 6166., 6150., 6252., 6074., 6129.5, 5844., 6205.5, 6383.5, 6345.5, 6610.5, 6505.5, 6582., 6527., 6599., 6756.5, 6701.5, 6667.5, 6303.5, 6370.5, 6246.5, 6212.5, 6246., 6348., 6719.5, 7318.5, 7384., 7467., 7333., 7401.5, 7391., 7719.5, 8391.5, 8177.5, 7922., 8188.5, 8230., 8219., 8172., 7727., 7604., 7539.5, 7410.5, 7005.5, 7019.5, 6931.5, 6712., 6274., 6536., 6137.5, 6240.5, 6309., 6245., 6193.5, 6267., 6306., 6578.5, 6394.5, 6487.5, 6253.5, 6467.5, 6351.5, 6521.5, 6685.5, 6727., 6701.5, 6906., 7076.5, 7032.5, 6977.5, 7016.5, 7196., 7295., 7260., 7354.5, 6689., 6487.5, 6397.5, 6180., 6240., 6300., 6278., 6321.5, 6487.5, 6478., 6516., 6493., 6247.5, 6328.5, 6385., 6482.5, 6747., 6709.5, 6703.5, 6578.5, 6429., 6452.5, 6686., 6620.5, 6582., 6599., 6571.5, 6503., 6464.5, 6553., 6582.5, 6551.5, 6570.5, 6608., 6591.5, 6530.5, 6154.5, 6180.5, 6193., 6181., 6436., 6456., 6438., 6394., 6384., 6408., 6413.5, 6412., 6394.5, 6412., 6393., 6406., 6406.5, 6408.5, 6266., 6271.5, 6307.5, 6336.5, 6345.5, 6333., 6427., 6404.5, 6450., 6510., 6413.5, 6338., 6353.5, 6361., 6337.5, 6249.5, 5586., 5581., 5510.5, 5502., 5556.5, 4738.5, 4348.5, 4536., 4266.5, 4283.5, 3768.5, 3931., 3724., 3773., 4219., 4244., 3972., 4136.5, 4094.5, 3829., 3902., 3695.5, 3430.5, 3369., 3397., 3526.5, 3405.5, 3340., 3432., 3257.5, 3193.5, 3183.5, 3189.5, 3496., 3665., 3680., 4069., 3841., 3978., 3943.5, 4034., 3777., 3806., 3587.5, 3890., 3711.5, 3831., 3693., 3824., 3888., 3784., 3817., 3794.5, 4038.5, 4005., 3995., 4001., 3622., 3632., 3613.5, 3514., 3663.5, 3575., 3607.5, 3637., 3609.5, 3681.5, 3535., 3529., 3576.5, 3550.5, 3567.5, 3560., 3555., 3527.5, 3428.5, 3391.5, 3434.5, 3413.5, 3436., 3464., 3414., 3405.5, 3428.5, 3365.5, 3357.5, 3625.5, 3626.5, 3648., 3590.5, 3587.5, 3576.5, 3560.5, 3564.5, 3579.5, 3623., 3867., 3888., 3938.5, 3897., 3938., 4111., 3733.5, 3817.5, 3797., 3798., 3788.5, 3802., 3808.5, 3785., 3699., 3846., 3848.5, 3854.5, 3840., 3915.5, 3898., 3845.5, 3857., 3848.5, 3855., 3897.5, 3987., 3961.5, 3968.5, 3996.5, 4030., 3969.5, 3979., 3977.5, 3966., 3903.5, 3916., 4026., 4009.5, 4085.5, 4090., 4091.5, 4132., 4898., 4979., 4909.5, 5041., 5043., 5192.5, 5280.5, 5184., 5321., 5038.5, 5075.5, 5066.5, 5159.5, 5024., 5202.5, 5227.5, 5278., 5287., 5319.5, 5296., 5382.5, 5530., 5440.5, 5119.5, 5149.5, 5161.5, 5153., 5140.5, 5263.5, 5317., 5385.5, 5657.5, 5769., 5715.5, 5684.5, 5738., 5939., 6142., 6341.5, 7218., 6972.5, 7827., 7997.5, 8203.5, 7884.5, 7352.5, 7258., 8206.5, 8009.5, 7958.5, 7624., 7875.5, 7997.5, 8067.5, 8749.5, 8779.5, 8721.5, 8665., 8274., 8546., 8555., 8737.5, 8100.5, 7663., 7783., 7804.5, 7996.5, 7926., 7629., 8016., 7917., 8176., 8234.5, 8695.5, 8859.5, 8975., 9347.5, 9086., 9289., 9532.5, 10262., 10692.5, 10841.5, 11046., 11760., 12930., 11156.5, 12374.5, 11869.5, 10761.5, 10568., 10840.5, 11983.5, 11143., 10991., 11234., 11475.5, 12288., 12563.5, 12094.5, 11336.5, 11803.5, 11370., 10185.5)
```

Why R doesn't work?
Is there any limit on its length?
Where can I read easy-to-read or standard document for R like [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/hello-world?tutorial-step=1),[C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/),[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/) having example?

OK,
`x<-read.table("c:\\users\\myaccount\\Documents\\for_R.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",")` 
does work as expected.
 but why my first code didn't work?

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/3 There is a limit on string length in the console

Comment: @anotherfred thank you,I want to accept your comment as an answer,would you re-post it?

Comment: @jay.sf I fixed my question tag.should I remove tag`r`?

Comment: @jay.sf this relates to R as well, not just RStudio, as explained at the link.

Comment: @jay.sf as mentioned at link this seems to affect only some R consoles, but it is clearly visible in the R core source and mailing list.

Comment: @Rnoob Since it relates to both I recommend to leave it as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has a limit on the string length allowed in the console. This is discussed in detail [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/3) which suggests a 4,095 byte limit to avoid an overflow issue.

Regarding a good resource for R, you can browse the official documentation on a function by typing `?` followed by the function name in the console, e.g. `?c` would bring up the documentation on the `c` function. For a good introduction there are a lot of good books on R such as those by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the introduction of the reference book. it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes
>   (not characters). [1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc)

There must also be an issue with RStudio.—R without RStudio can handle an input at least twice as large as `x`:

```
> x <- c(11210., 11252., 11546.5, 12746.5, 11560., 10792.5, 10830., 11394.5, 11117., 11110., 11398., 11631.5, 11127., 9990., 10132., 9008., 8807.5, 9226.5, 8151., 6889.5, 7674.5, 7598.5, 8232.5, 8675.5, 8548.5, 8065., 8905.5, 8499.5, 9462.5, 10008., 10185.5, 11144., 10402., 11173., 11220., 10455., 9831.5, 10130.5, 9689., 9590.5, 10317., 10530., 10319., 10919.5, 11030., 11457.5, 11490.5, 11331.5, 10730., 9913.5, 9304.5, 9224., 8789.5, 9543., 9093., 9133.5, 8190.5, 8250.5, 8250.5, 7849., 8189., 8590., 8897., 8893.5, 8700., 8921., 8512., 8444.5, 8150., 7791., 7935., 7082., 6820., 6920.5, 6817., 7046.5, 7408.5, 6779., 6769.5, 6612., 6900.5, 7014., 6763., 6824., 6933.5, 7904.5, 7887.5, 8000., 8346.5, 8047., 7889.5, 8177., 8266., 8847., 8923.5, 8800., 8943., 9675.5, 8844., 9288., 8928., 9343.5, 9401., 9250.5, 9065.5, 9216., 9742., 9682.5, 9829., 9601., 9359., 9190.5, 9305.5, 9027., 8413., 8476., 8693., 8678., 8477.5, 8332., 8058.5, 8233., 8230., 8521.5, 8397., 7989., 7506., 7568., 7464.5, 7323., 7336.5, 7111., 7469., 7372., 7485.5, 7513., 7631., 7709., 7615.5, 7657., 7689.5, 7625.5, 7492.5, 6767., 6870.5, 6553.5, 6296., 6631.5, 6394.5, 6488., 6443., 6707., 6732., 6750., 6710.5, 6049., 6166., 6150., 6252., 6074., 6129.5, 5844., 6205.5, 6383.5, 6345.5, 6610.5, 6505.5, 6582., 6527., 6599., 6756.5, 6701.5, 6667.5, 6303.5, 6370.5, 6246.5, 6212.5, 6246., 6348., 6719.5, 7318.5, 7384., 7467., 7333., 7401.5, 7391., 7719.5, 8391.5, 8177.5, 7922., 8188.5, 8230., 8219., 8172., 7727., 7604., 7539.5, 7410.5, 7005.5, 7019.5, 6931.5, 6712., 6274., 6536., 6137.5, 6240.5, 6309., 6245., 6193.5, 6267., 6306., 6578.5, 6394.5, 6487.5, 6253.5, 6467.5, 6351.5, 6521.5, 6685.5, 6727., 6701.5, 6906., 7076.5, 7032.5, 6977.5, 7016.5, 7196., 7295., 7260., 7354.5, 6689., 6487.5, 6397.5, 6180., 6240., 6300., 6278., 6321.5, 6487.5, 6478., 6516., 6493., 6247.5, 6328.5, 6385., 6482.5, 6747., 6709.5, 6703.5, 6578.5, 6429., 6452.5, 6686., 6620.5, 6582., 6599., 6571.5, 6503., 6464.5, 6553., 6582.5, 6551.5, 6570.5, 6608., 6591.5, 6530.5, 6154.5, 6180.5, 6193., 6181., 6436., 6456., 6438., 6394., 6384., 6408., 6413.5, 6412., 6394.5, 6412., 6393., 6406., 6406.5, 6408.5, 6266., 6271.5, 6307.5, 6336.5, 6345.5, 6333., 6427., 6404.5, 6450., 6510., 6413.5, 6338., 6353.5, 6361., 6337.5, 6249.5, 5586., 5581., 5510.5, 5502., 5556.5, 4738.5, 4348.5, 4536., 4266.5, 4283.5, 3768.5, 3931., 3724., 3773., 4219., 4244., 3972., 4136.5, 4094.5, 3829., 3902., 3695.5, 3430.5, 3369., 3397., 3526.5, 3405.5, 3340., 3432., 3257.5, 3193.5, 3183.5, 3189.5, 3496., 3665., 3680., 4069., 3841., 3978., 3943.5, 4034., 3777., 3806., 3587.5, 3890., 3711.5, 3831., 3693., 3824., 3888., 3784., 3817., 3794.5, 4038.5, 4005., 3995., 4001., 3622., 3632., 3613.5, 3514., 3663.5, 3575., 3607.5, 3637., 3609.5, 3681.5, 3535., 3529., 3576.5, 3550.5, 3567.5, 3560., 3555., 3527.5, 3428.5, 3391.5, 3434.5, 3413.5, 3436., 3464., 3414., 3405.5, 3428.5, 3365.5, 3357.5, 3625.5, 3626.5, 3648., 3590.5, 3587.5, 3576.5, 3560.5, 3564.5, 3579.5, 3623., 3867., 3888., 3938.5, 3897., 3938., 4111., 3733.5, 3817.5, 3797., 3798., 3788.5, 3802., 3808.5, 3785., 3699., 3846., 3848.5, 3854.5, 3840., 3915.5, 3898., 3845.5, 3857., 3848.5, 3855., 3897.5, 3987., 3961.5, 3968.5, 3996.5, 4030., 3969.5, 3979., 3977.5, 3966., 3903.5, 3916., 4026., 4009.5, 4085.5, 4090., 4091.5, 4132., 4898., 4979., 4909.5, 5041., 5043., 5192.5, 5280.5, 5184., 5321., 5038.5, 5075.5, 5066.5, 5159.5, 5024., 5202.5, 5227.5, 5278., 5287., 5319.5, 5296., 5382.5, 5530., 5440.5, 5119.5, 5149.5, 5161.5, 5153., 5140.5, 5263.5, 5317., 5385.5, 5657.5, 5769., 5715.5, 5684.5, 5738., 5939., 6142., 6341.5, 7218., 6972.5, 7827., 7997.5, 8203.5, 7884.5, 7352.5, 7258., 8206.5, 8009.5, 7958.5, 7624., 7875.5, 7997.5, 8067.5, 8749.5, 8779.5, 8721.5, 8665., 8274., 8546., 8555., 8737.5, 8100.5, 7663., 7783., 7804.5, 7996.5, 7926., 7629., 8016., 7917., 8176., 8234.5, 8695.5, 8859.5, 8975., 9347.5, 9086., 9289., 9532.5, 10262., 10692.5, 10841.5, 11046., 11760., 12930., 11156.5, 12374.5, 11869.5, 10761.5, 10568., 10840.5, 11983.5, 11143., 10991., 11234., 11475.5, 12288., 12563.5, 12094.5, 1
+ 1336.5, 11803.5, 11370., 10185.5, 11210., 11252., 11546.5, 12746.5, 11560., 10792.5, 10830., 11394.5, 11117., 11110., 11398., 11631.5, 11127., 9990., 10132., 9008., 8807.5, 9226.5, 8151., 6889.5, 7674.5, 7598.5, 8232.5, 8675.5, 8548.5, 8065., 8905.5, 8499.5, 9462.5, 10008., 10185.5, 11144., 10402., 11173., 11220., 10455., 9831.5, 10130.5, 9689., 9590.5, 10317., 10530., 10319., 10919.5, 11030., 11457.5, 11490.5, 11331.5, 10730., 9913.5, 9304.5, 9224., 8789.5, 9543., 9093., 9133.5, 8190.5, 8250.5, 8250.5, 7849., 8189., 8590., 8897., 8893.5, 8700., 8921., 8512., 8444.5, 8150., 7791., 7935., 7082., 6820., 6920.5, 6817., 7046.5, 7408.5, 6779., 6769.5, 6612., 6900.5, 7014., 6763., 6824., 6933.5, 7904.5, 7887.5, 8000., 8346.5, 8047., 7889.5, 8177., 8266., 8847., 8923.5, 8800., 8943., 9675.5, 8844., 9288., 8928., 9343.5, 9401., 9250.5, 9065.5, 9216., 9742., 9682.5, 9829., 9601., 9359., 9190.5, 9305.5, 9027., 8413., 8476., 8693., 8678., 8477.5, 8332., 8058.5, 8233., 8230., 8521.5, 8397., 7989., 7506., 7568., 7464.5, 7323., 7336.5, 7111., 7469., 7372., 7485.5, 7513., 7631., 7709., 7615.5, 7657., 7689.5, 7625.5, 7492.5, 6767., 6870.5, 6553.5, 6296., 6631.5, 6394.5, 6488., 6443., 6707., 6732., 6750., 6710.5, 6049., 6166., 6150., 6252., 6074., 6129.5, 5844., 6205.5, 6383.5, 6345.5, 6610.5, 6505.5, 6582., 6527., 6599., 6756.5, 6701.5, 6667.5, 6303.5, 6370.5, 6246.5, 6212.5, 6246., 6348., 6719.5, 7318.5, 7384., 7467., 7333., 7401.5, 7391., 7719.5, 8391.5, 8177.5, 7922., 8188.5, 8230., 8219., 8172., 7727., 7604., 7539.5, 7410.5, 7005.5, 7019.5, 6931.5, 6712., 6274., 6536., 6137.5, 6240.5, 6309., 6245., 6193.5, 6267., 6306., 6578.5, 6394.5, 6487.5, 6253.5, 6467.5, 6351.5, 6521.5, 6685.5, 6727., 6701.5, 6906., 7076.5, 7032.5, 6977.5, 7016.5, 7196., 7295., 7260., 7354.5, 6689., 6487.5, 6397.5, 6180., 6240., 6300., 6278., 6321.5, 6487.5, 6478., 6516., 6493., 6247.5, 6328.5, 6385., 6482.5, 6747., 6709.5, 6703.5, 6578.5, 6429., 6452.5, 6686., 6620.5, 6582., 6599., 6571.5, 6503., 6464.5, 6553., 6582.5, 6551.5, 6570.5, 6608., 6591.5, 6530.5, 6154.5, 6180.5, 6193., 6181., 6436., 6456., 6438., 6394., 6384., 6408., 6413.5, 6412., 6394.5, 6412., 6393., 6406., 6406.5, 6408.5, 6266., 6271.5, 6307.5, 6336.5, 6345.5, 6333., 6427., 6404.5, 6450., 6510., 6413.5, 6338., 6353.5, 6361., 6337.5, 6249.5, 5586., 5581., 5510.5, 5502., 5556.5, 4738.5, 4348.5, 4536., 4266.5, 4283.5, 3768.5, 3931., 3724., 3773., 4219., 4244., 3972., 4136.5, 4094.5, 3829., 3902., 3695.5, 3430.5, 3369., 3397., 3526.5, 3405.5, 3340., 3432., 3257.5, 3193.5, 3183.5, 3189.5, 3496., 3665., 3680., 4069., 3841., 3978., 3943.5, 4034., 3777., 3806., 3587.5, 3890., 3711.5, 3831., 3693., 3824., 3888., 3784., 3817., 3794.5, 4038.5, 4005., 3995., 4001., 3622., 3632., 3613.5, 3514., 3663.5, 3575., 3607.5, 3637., 3609.5, 3681.5, 3535., 3529., 3576.5, 3550.5, 3567.5, 3560., 3555., 3527.5, 3428.5, 3391.5, 3434.5, 3413.5, 3436., 3464., 3414., 3405.5, 3428.5, 3365.5, 3357.5, 3625.5, 3626.5, 3648., 3590.5, 3587.5, 3576.5, 3560.5, 3564.5, 3579.5, 3623., 3867., 3888., 3938.5, 3897., 3938., 4111., 3733.5, 3817.5, 3797., 3798., 3788.5, 3802., 3808.5, 3785., 3699., 3846., 3848.5, 3854.5, 3840., 3915.5, 3898., 3845.5, 3857., 3848.5, 3855., 3897.5, 3987., 3961.5, 3968.5, 3996.5, 4030., 3969.5, 3979., 3977.5, 3966., 3903.5, 3916., 4026., 4009.5, 4085.5, 4090., 4091.5, 4132., 4898., 4979., 4909.5, 5041., 5043., 5192.5, 5280.5, 5184., 5321., 5038.5, 5075.5, 5066.5, 5159.5, 5024., 5202.5, 5227.5, 5278., 5287., 5319.5, 5296., 5382.5, 5530., 5440.5, 5119.5, 5149.5, 5161.5, 5153., 5140.5, 5263.5, 5317., 5385.5, 5657.5, 5769., 5715.5, 5684.5, 5738., 5939., 6142., 6341.5, 7218., 6972.5, 7827., 7997.5, 8203.5, 7884.5, 7352.5, 7258., 8206.5, 8009.5, 7958.5, 7624., 7875.5, 7997.5, 8067.5, 8749.5, 8779.5, 8721.5, 8665., 8274., 8546., 8555., 8737.5, 8100.5, 7663., 7783., 7804.5, 7996.5, 7926., 7629., 8016., 7917., 8176., 8234.5, 8695.5, 8859.5, 8975., 9347.5, 9086., 9289., 9532.5, 10262., 10692.5, 10841.5, 11046., 11760., 12930., 11156.5, 12374.5, 11869.5, 10761.5, 10568., 10840.5, 11983.5, 11143., 10991., 11234., 11475.5
+ , 12288., 12563.5, 12094.5, 11336.5, 11803.5, 11370., 10185.5)
> x
   [1] 11210.0 11252.0 11546.5 12746.5 11560.0 10792.5 10830.0 11394.5 11117.0 11110.0 11398.0 11631.5 11127.0  9990.0 10132.0  9008.0  8807.5  9226.5  8151.0  6889.5  7674.5  7598.5  8232.5  8675.5  8548.5  8065.0  8905.5  8499.5
  [29]  9462.5 10008.0 10185.5 11144.0 10402.0 11173.0 11220.0 10455.0  9831.5 10130.5  9689.0  9590.5 10317.0 10530.0 10319.0 10919.5 11030.0 11457.5 11490.5 11331.5 10730.0  9913.5  9304.5  9224.0  8789.5  9543.0  9093.0  9133.5
  [57]  8190.5  8250.5  8250.5  7849.0  8189.0  8590.0  8897.0  8893.5  8700.0  8921.0  8512.0  8444.5  8150.0  7791.0  7935.0  7082.0  6820.0  6920.5  6817.0  7046.5  7408.5  6779.0  6769.5  6612.0  6900.5  7014.0  6763.0  6824.0
  [85]  6933.5  7904.5  7887.5  8000.0  8346.5  8047.0  7889.5  8177.0  8266.0  8847.0  8923.5  8800.0  8943.0  9675.5  8844.0  9288.0  8928.0  9343.5  9401.0  9250.5  9065.5  9216.0  9742.0  9682.5  9829.0  9601.0  9359.0  9190.5
 [113]  9305.5  9027.0  8413.0  8476.0  8693.0  8678.0  8477.5  8332.0  8058.5  8233.0  8230.0  8521.5  8397.0  7989.0  7506.0  7568.0  7464.5  7323.0  7336.5  7111.0  7469.0  7372.0  7485.5  7513.0  7631.0  7709.0  7615.5  7657.0
 [141]  7689.5  7625.5  7492.5  6767.0  6870.5  6553.5  6296.0  6631.5  6394.5  6488.0  6443.0  6707.0  6732.0  6750.0  6710.5  6049.0  6166.0  6150.0  6252.0  6074.0  6129.5  5844.0  6205.5  6383.5  6345.5  6610.5  6505.5  6582.0
 [169]  6527.0  6599.0  6756.5  6701.5  6667.5  6303.5  6370.5  6246.5  6212.5  6246.0  6348.0  6719.5  7318.5  7384.0  7467.0  7333.0  7401.5  7391.0  7719.5  8391.5  8177.5  7922.0  8188.5  8230.0  8219.0  8172.0  7727.0  7604.0
 [197]  7539.5  7410.5  7005.5  7019.5  6931.5  6712.0  6274.0  6536.0  6137.5  6240.5  6309.0  6245.0  6193.5  6267.0  6306.0  6578.5  6394.5  6487.5  6253.5  6467.5  6351.5  6521.5  6685.5  6727.0  6701.5  6906.0  7076.5  7032.5
 [225]  6977.5  7016.5  7196.0  7295.0  7260.0  7354.5  6689.0  6487.5  6397.5  6180.0  6240.0  6300.0  6278.0  6321.5  6487.5  6478.0  6516.0  6493.0  6247.5  6328.5  6385.0  6482.5  6747.0  6709.5  6703.5  6578.5  6429.0  6452.5
 [253]  6686.0  6620.5  6582.0  6599.0  6571.5  6503.0  6464.5  6553.0  6582.5  6551.5  6570.5  6608.0  6591.5  6530.5  6154.5  6180.5  6193.0  6181.0  6436.0  6456.0  6438.0  6394.0  6384.0  6408.0  6413.5  6412.0  6394.5  6412.0
 [281]  6393.0  6406.0  6406.5  6408.5  6266.0  6271.5  6307.5  6336.5  6345.5  6333.0  6427.0  6404.5  6450.0  6510.0  6413.5  6338.0  6353.5  6361.0  6337.5  6249.5  5586.0  5581.0  5510.5  5502.0  5556.5  4738.5  4348.5  4536.0
 [309]  4266.5  4283.5  3768.5  3931.0  3724.0  3773.0  4219.0  4244.0  3972.0  4136.5  4094.5  3829.0  3902.0  3695.5  3430.5  3369.0  3397.0  3526.5  3405.5  3340.0  3432.0  3257.5  3193.5  3183.5  3189.5  3496.0  3665.0  3680.0
 [337]  4069.0  3841.0  3978.0  3943.5  4034.0  3777.0  3806.0  3587.5  3890.0  3711.5  3831.0  3693.0  3824.0  3888.0  3784.0  3817.0  3794.5  4038.5  4005.0  3995.0  4001.0  3622.0  3632.0  3613.5  3514.0  3663.5  3575.0  3607.5
 [365]  3637.0  3609.5  3681.5  3535.0  3529.0  3576.5  3550.5  3567.5  3560.0  3555.0  3527.5  3428.5  3391.5  3434.5  3413.5  3436.0  3464.0  3414.0  3405.5  3428.5  3365.5  3357.5  3625.5  3626.5  3648.0  3590.5  3587.5  3576.5
 [393]  3560.5  3564.5  3579.5  3623.0  3867.0  3888.0  3938.5  3897.0  3938.0  4111.0  3733.5  3817.5  3797.0  3798.0  3788.5  3802.0  3808.5  3785.0  3699.0  3846.0  3848.5  3854.5  3840.0  3915.5  3898.0  3845.5  3857.0  3848.5
 [421]  3855.0  3897.5  3987.0  3961.5  3968.5  3996.5  4030.0  3969.5  3979.0  3977.5  3966.0  3903.5  3916.0  4026.0  4009.5  4085.5  4090.0  4091.5  4132.0  4898.0  4979.0  4909.5  5041.0  5043.0  5192.5  5280.5  5184.0  5321.0
 [449]  5038.5  5075.5  5066.5  5159.5  5024.0  5202.5  5227.5  5278.0  5287.0  5319.5  5296.0  5382.5  5530.0  5440.5  5119.5  5149.5  5161.5  5153.0  5140.5  5263.5  5317.0  5385.5  5657.5  5769.0  5715.5  5684.5  5738.0  5939.0
 [477]  6142.0  6341.5  7218.0  6972.5  7827.0  7997.5  8203.5  7884.5  7352.5  7258.0  8206.5  8009.5  7958.5  7624.0  7875.5  7997.5  8067.5  8749.5  8779.5  8721.5  8665.0  8274.0  8546.0  8555.0  8737.5  8100.5  7663.0  7783.0
 [505]  7804.5  7996.5  7926.0  7629.0  8016.0  7917.0  8176.0  8234.5  8695.5  8859.5  8975.0  9347.5  9086.0  9289.0  9532.5 10262.0 10692.5 10841.5 11046.0 11760.0 12930.0 11156.5 12374.5 11869.5 10761.5 10568.0 10840.5 11983.5
 [533] 11143.0 10991.0 11234.0 11475.5 12288.0 12563.5 12094.5  1336.5 11803.5 11370.0 10185.5 11210.0 11252.0 11546.5 12746.5 11560.0 10792.5 10830.0 11394.5 11117.0 11110.0 11398.0 11631.5 11127.0  9990.0 10132.0  9008.0  8807.5
 [561]  9226.5  8151.0  6889.5  7674.5  7598.5  8232.5  8675.5  8548.5  8065.0  8905.5  8499.5  9462.5 10008.0 10185.5 11144.0 10402.0 11173.0 11220.0 10455.0  9831.5 10130.5  9689.0  9590.5 10317.0 10530.0 10319.0 10919.5 11030.0
 [589] 11457.5 11490.5 11331.5 10730.0  9913.5  9304.5  9224.0  8789.5  9543.0  9093.0  9133.5  8190.5  8250.5  8250.5  7849.0  8189.0  8590.0  8897.0  8893.5  8700.0  8921.0  8512.0  8444.5  8150.0  7791.0  7935.0  7082.0  6820.0
 [617]  6920.5  6817.0  7046.5  7408.5  6779.0  6769.5  6612.0  6900.5  7014.0  6763.0  6824.0  6933.5  7904.5  7887.5  8000.0  8346.5  8047.0  7889.5  8177.0  8266.0  8847.0  8923.5  8800.0  8943.0  9675.5  8844.0  9288.0  8928.0
 [645]  9343.5  9401.0  9250.5  9065.5  9216.0  9742.0  9682.5  9829.0  9601.0  9359.0  9190.5  9305.5  9027.0  8413.0  8476.0  8693.0  8678.0  8477.5  8332.0  8058.5  8233.0  8230.0  8521.5  8397.0  7989.0  7506.0  7568.0  7464.5
 [673]  7323.0  7336.5  7111.0  7469.0  7372.0  7485.5  7513.0  7631.0  7709.0  7615.5  7657.0  7689.5  7625.5  7492.5  6767.0  6870.5  6553.5  6296.0  6631.5  6394.5  6488.0  6443.0  6707.0  6732.0  6750.0  6710.5  6049.0  6166.0
 [701]  6150.0  6252.0  6074.0  6129.5  5844.0  6205.5  6383.5  6345.5  6610.5  6505.5  6582.0  6527.0  6599.0  6756.5  6701.5  6667.5  6303.5  6370.5  6246.5  6212.5  6246.0  6348.0  6719.5  7318.5  7384.0  7467.0  7333.0  7401.5
 [729]  7391.0  7719.5  8391.5  8177.5  7922.0  8188.5  8230.0  8219.0  8172.0  7727.0  7604.0  7539.5  7410.5  7005.5  7019.5  6931.5  6712.0  6274.0  6536.0  6137.5  6240.5  6309.0  6245.0  6193.5  6267.0  6306.0  6578.5  6394.5
 [757]  6487.5  6253.5  6467.5  6351.5  6521.5  6685.5  6727.0  6701.5  6906.0  7076.5  7032.5  6977.5  7016.5  7196.0  7295.0  7260.0  7354.5  6689.0  6487.5  6397.5  6180.0  6240.0  6300.0  6278.0  6321.5  6487.5  6478.0  6516.0
 [785]  6493.0  6247.5  6328.5  6385.0  6482.5  6747.0  6709.5  6703.5  6578.5  6429.0  6452.5  6686.0  6620.5  6582.0  6599.0  6571.5  6503.0  6464.5  6553.0  6582.5  6551.5  6570.5  6608.0  6591.5  6530.5  6154.5  6180.5  6193.0
 [813]  6181.0  6436.0  6456.0  6438.0  6394.0  6384.0  6408.0  6413.5  6412.0  6394.5  6412.0  6393.0  6406.0  6406.5  6408.5  6266.0  6271.5  6307.5  6336.5  6345.5  6333.0  6427.0  6404.5  6450.0  6510.0  6413.5  6338.0  6353.5
 [841]  6361.0  6337.5  6249.5  5586.0  5581.0  5510.5  5502.0  5556.5  4738.5  4348.5  4536.0  4266.5  4283.5  3768.5  3931.0  3724.0  3773.0  4219.0  4244.0  3972.0  4136.5  4094.5  3829.0  3902.0  3695.5  3430.5  3369.0  3397.0
 [869]  3526.5  3405.5  3340.0  3432.0  3257.5  3193.5  3183.5  3189.5  3496.0  3665.0  3680.0  4069.0  3841.0  3978.0  3943.5  4034.0  3777.0  3806.0  3587.5  3890.0  3711.5  3831.0  3693.0  3824.0  3888.0  3784.0  3817.0  3794.5
 [897]  4038.5  4005.0  3995.0  4001.0  3622.0  3632.0  3613.5  3514.0  3663.5  3575.0  3607.5  3637.0  3609.5  3681.5  3535.0  3529.0  3576.5  3550.5  3567.5  3560.0  3555.0  3527.5  3428.5  3391.5  3434.5  3413.5  3436.0  3464.0
 [925]  3414.0  3405.5  3428.5  3365.5  3357.5  3625.5  3626.5  3648.0  3590.5  3587.5  3576.5  3560.5  3564.5  3579.5  3623.0  3867.0  3888.0  3938.5  3897.0  3938.0  4111.0  3733.5  3817.5  3797.0  3798.0  3788.5  3802.0  3808.5
 [953]  3785.0  3699.0  3846.0  3848.5  3854.5  3840.0  3915.5  3898.0  3845.5  3857.0  3848.5  3855.0  3897.5  3987.0  3961.5  3968.5  3996.5  4030.0  3969.5  3979.0  3977.5  3966.0  3903.5  3916.0  4026.0  4009.5  4085.5  4090.0
 [981]  4091.5  4132.0  4898.0  4979.0  4909.5  5041.0  5043.0  5192.5  5280.5  5184.0  5321.0  5038.5  5075.5  5066.5  5159.5  5024.0  5202.5  5227.5  5278.0  5287.0  5319.5  5296.0  5382.5  5530.0  5440.5  5119.5  5149.5  5161.5
[1009]  5153.0  5140.5  5263.5  5317.0  5385.5  5657.5  5769.0  5715.5  5684.5  5738.0  5939.0  6142.0  6341.5  7218.0  6972.5  7827.0  7997.5  8203.5  7884.5  7352.5  7258.0  8206.5  8009.5  7958.5  7624.0  7875.5  7997.5  8067.5
[1037]  8749.5  8779.5  8721.5  8665.0  8274.0  8546.0  8555.0  8737.5  8100.5  7663.0  7783.0  7804.5  7996.5  7926.0  7629.0  8016.0  7917.0  8176.0  8234.5  8695.5  8859.5  8975.0  9347.5  9086.0  9289.0  9532.5 10262.0 10692.5
[1065] 10841.5 11046.0 11760.0 12930.0 11156.5 12374.5 11869.5 10761.5 10568.0 10840.5 11983.5 11143.0 10991.0 11234.0 11475.0 12288.0 12563.5 12094.5 11336.5 11803.5 11370.0 10185.5
>
```

Comment: your console is normal terminal(something like`bash` in `Linux`) not RStudio? or another IDE for R?

Comment: @Rnoob RStudio is just an IDE for R and won't work without an installation of R. You may also start R without IDE.